# Testing a tensorflow network: in_top_k() replacement for multilabel classification

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, multilabel-classification

I've created a neural network in tensorflow. This network is multilabel. Ergo: it tries to predict multiple output labels for one input set, in this case three. Currently I use this code to test how accurate my network is at predicting the three labels:

```
_, indices_1 = tf.nn.top_k(prediction, 3)
_, indices_2 = tf.nn.top_k(item_data, 3)
correct = tf.equal(indices_1, indices_2)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
percentage = accuracy.eval({champion_data:input_data,  item_data:output_data})
```

That code works fine. The problem is now that I'm trying to create code that tests if the top 3 items it finds in indices_1 are amongst the top 5 images in indices_2. I know tensorflow has an in_top_k() method, but as far as I know that doesn't accept multilabel. Currently I've been trying to compare them using a for loop:

```
_, indices_1 = tf.nn.top_k(prediction, 5)
_, indices_2 = tf.nn.top_k(item_data, 3)
indices_1 = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(indices_1, (1, 0)))
indices_2 = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(indices_2, (1, 0)))
correct = []
for element in indices_1:
    for element_2 in indices_2:
        if element == element_2:
            correct.append(True)
        else:
            correct.append(False)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
percentage = accuracy.eval({champion_data:input_data, item_data:output_data})
```

However, that doesn't work. Mainly because I don't have a clue what I'm doing when it comes to tf.unpack and tf.transpose.

If I leave the transpose out it gives the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, 5)

If the transpose is in there the code runs but my accuracy is always 0.0.

**So I have one of two questions:**

1) Is there an easy replacement for in_top_k() that accepts multilabel classification that I can use instead of custom writing code?

2) If not 1: what am I doing wrong that results in me getting an accuracy of 0.0?